# keyboard | symbol not working

Tags: keyboard

on ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS with Dvorak and us keyboard layout
The laptop has the pipe | symbol above the right enter key. But instead of the pipe symbol the key prints the < symbol to the screen.
How can I fix this?
Than you

Comment: What language is Ubuntu set to?

Comment: originally it was set for English Dvorak. But also when set to English US - it was not doing the | symbol. But I changed it to the UK keyboard and the | is where it needs to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will fix that by selecting a keyboard layout that matches that of your keyboard in " Settings" - "Keyboard" - " Input sources".

Add a keyboard layout first (using the <kbd>+</kbd> icon), and if that works, you could delete the layout that was there first.

Comment: Thank you.I always thought my laptop's keyboard is a US one - it was bought in the US. But I changed hte layout to the UK and it seems to work. Not sure why.